# How to render stored images with multer in MEAN stack application

Tags: angularjs

I am uploading images using `multer`.

I am able to store images in folder and also able to save their names in `mongoDb`.
But now while fetching collection, I am unable to view images in my html page.

I am doing like this `<img class="thumb" ng-src="{{'data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,' + product.imagePaths[0]}}" height="500" width="500">`
`imagePaths` contains array of images, I want to display only first image.

`image paths: {{product.imagePaths[0]}}` shows correct file name, but nothing is visible.
Please help.

Comment: If you are sending a path it is not base 64 encoded data. You probably just want `ng-src="{{ product.imagePaths[0]}}"`

Comment: Hmm, did that still not working

Comment: Actually, i am saving image name in collection, and storing image in folder.

Comment: Store the folder path also unless it is a known and you can hard code a variable to build the path from. Use your browser dev tools network to see the request it makes for each image and look at the url path and adjust accordingly

Comment: Ok, but now I am thinking is to convert image to base64 format, and then post base64 data to database. Wht do you think of this approach?

Comment: Will make the json data a lot larger instead of letting browser get only the images it needs after data is received

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159803/discussion-between-mayank-bisht-and-charlietfl).